# POST Request to upload multipart file in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, multipart, postman

I'm using spring boot, I need to upload a multipart file (jpg or png file). I need to send a (POST request to upload the multi part file using "postman"), can anyone provide a screen shot of  "postman" of how to set it up to do that or tell me? Thanks.

method :

```html
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upload")
 @ResponseBody
 ResponseEntity<?> writeUserProfilePhoto(@PathVariable Long user,  @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws Throwable {
  
  byte bytesForProfilePhoto[] = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(file.getInputStream()); //Return an InputStream to read the contents of the file from.
  
  this.crmService.writeUserProfilePhoto(user, MediaType.parseMediaType(file.getContentType()),bytesForProfilePhoto);
  
  HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  
  URI uriOfPhoto = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
    .pathSegment(("/users" + "/{user}" + "/photo").substring(1))
    .buildAndExpand(Collections.singletonMap("user", user)).toUri();
  
  httpHeaders.setLocation(uriOfPhoto);
  return new ResponseEntity<>(httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
 }
```

and this is how I sent the POST request:[image]

my configuration class:

```html
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({ Servlet.class, StandardServletMultipartResolver.class, MultipartConfigElement.class })
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "multipart", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MultipartProperties.class)
public class MultipartAutoConfiguration {

 @Autowired
 private MultipartProperties multipartProperties = new MultipartProperties();

 @Bean
 @ConditionalOnMissingBean
 public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
  return this.multipartProperties.createMultipartConfig();
 }

 @Bean(name = DispatcherServlet.MULTIPART_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME)
 @ConditionalOnMissingBean(MultipartResolver.class)
 public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
  return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
 }

}
```

Comment: Refer to postman [docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests).

Comment: Not a [tag:java] question. More of a question about how to use a tool.

Comment: Thanks I will check it :)

Comment: @nobeh in that doc I didn't find it. I just get the following exception:

Comment: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Comment: want to know is there anything wrong with my code or the way I send the POST request, I get 500 status code along with the exception.

Comment: Please post the Java method that handles the file upload and the exception so that we can get a better understanding of in the question.

Comment: Sure, this is the method:

Comment: @nobeh  you can see it . Now I get status code 400

Answer (score 3):

The error in postman says

> Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

The method signature looks fine defining `file` parameter:

```
ResponseEntity<?> writeUserProfilePhoto(
  @PathVariable Long user,  @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) 
    throws Throwable
```

The issue is that when using postman, you're using `dog1` as the name of this parameter. Change it to `file` to match the expected parameter name for the multipart file.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I spent time to find that, you helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me.

```html
The error in postman says

Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present
The method signature looks fine defining file parameter:

ResponseEntity<?> writeUserProfilePhoto(
  @PathVariable Long user,  @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) 
    throws Throwable
The issue is that when using postman, you're using dog1 as the name of this parameter. Change it to file to match the expected parameter name for the multipart file.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public Response uploadImage(String token, MultipartFile file) {


    long id=tokenUtil.decodeToken(token);
    Optional<User> user=userRepo.findById(id);
    if(!user.isPresent()) {
        throw new UserException(-5, "User does not exists");

    }
    UUID uuid=UUID.randomUUID();
    String uniqueUserId=uuid.toString();
    try {

        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), fileLocation.resolve(uniqueUserId), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        user.get().setProfilePic(uniqueUserId);
        userRepo.save(user.get());
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return ResponseHelper.statusResponse(200, "Profile Pic Uploaded Successfully");


}
```

Comment: Add some explanation to avoid this post to consider as low quality post by stackoverflow.